# Capacitive projectile triggering touch screen

Tags: capacitor, touchscreen, capacitive

I've read through a number of questions ([How can a capacitive touch screen be triggered without human contact?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23036/how-can-a-capacitive-touch-screen-be-triggered-without-human-contact)), ([How to use a capacitive touch screen without a human hand](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60385/how-to-use-a-capacitive-touch-screen-without-a-human-hand)), ([What is the minimal capacitor (capitor type/size/capacity) needed to fool a capacitive touch screen?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188920/what-is-the-minimal-capacitor-capitor-type-size-capacity-needed-to-fool-a-capa)) around capacitive touch screens and triggering touches without contact to the human body (none of which actually have accepted answers as it turns out).

I have been able to reproduce a few devices that can occasionally trigger a touch on an iPad screen while insulated from the hand that's holding it.

However in my experiment, I want to be able to launch a projectile (like a nerf bullet) at an iPad screen and have it register as a touch. So far nothing I have tried has worked. I think there are 2 issues at play:

1. No "ground" - the projectile can't be tethered so it can't be connected to ground in any reliable way
2. Response time - the projectile hits and bounces off very quickly. I believe this is also part of the problem.

How can increase the self-capacitance of my projectile so it can effectively register a very rapid but consistent touch?

Can I add a capacitor or something else to increase the effectiveness of such a projectile? A battery?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought (this may or may not work)

Newer iPhones and some iPads support 3DTouch (they can measure the force pressing on the screen).

If you have something constantly touching the screen to register touches, and then hit the screen with a nerf dart, perhaps the measured force will go up?

Comment: Nice thought! Will have to try that.